# Infopath last name validation pattern single quote

Tags: regex, sharepoint, infopath

I'm trying to create a validation matching pattern in InfoPath for a last name that will not allow characters that are outside the set of A-Z or a-z. The issue is I can't seem to include common other characters in the last name like a single quote. The pattern below is the closest I can get. It allows a space and a dash but I can't figure out how to allow a single quote (ex. O'Brien). Any ideas?

```
[a-zA-Z]([ ]*-*[a-zA-Z])*
```

Comment: Just add all the characters to the same set `[a-zA-Z- ']`

Comment: InfoPath seems to have different rules because it will take [a-zA-Z ] but it won't take [a-zA-Z '-] or [a-zA-Z -] or [a-zA-Z ']. It always comes back with "invalid pattern".

Comment: So apparently [infopath's old? regex engine is weird](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/input-scopes-for-infopath-controls-16549a86-55e0-49eb-a536-c27f06028ec6#bm2c). Try using `([a-zA-Z]|'|\-| )*`. Maybe that'll work for you, although my first comment really should work.

Comment: It is very odd. That doesn't work either. It does seem to not mind the ` character but it does mind the ' character. I can't seem to find any documentation that explains why.

Comment: try escaping it? Idk